# Jenkins- Process getting stuck on getting started page for plugins installation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[image]I have installed Jenkins on Linux CentOS, after setting up the proxy it asks to install plugins, i selected few plugins and after proceeding to install them some of them failed and the install bar completes for other plugins but the page hangs forever and i am not able to proceed further.

Attached image for reference.

Please suggest !

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, tried:

- refreshing page
- force refresh
- restarting Jenkins
- restarting machine

Eventually  just opened up the folder and removed the `.hpi` entries for those items. I didn't want to install them in the first place.